# Modular arithmetic - solving logarithmic equation given logarithmic list of different base

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we are working in a prime modulus $p$, and we are given a list of the discrete logarithms of a particular base $b$ which is a primitive root.

What is the significance of that list of discrete logarithms to solving equations of the form $x^e \equiv n$, where $e$ and $n$ are known, but it is not necessarily true that $x=b$?

As an example, suppose we are in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ are given the list of discrete logarithms where $b=7$:

$log_7(1)=0$

$log_7(2)=3$

$log_7(3)=4$

$log_7(4)=6$

$log_7(5)=2$

$log_7(6)=7$

$log_7(7)=1$

$log_7(8)=9$

$log_7(9)=8$

$log_7(10)=5$

How might this help us solve the congruence $x^7 \equiv 3$? It is clear to see from this list that $b \not= 7$, as $log_7(6)=7$, so $7^7=6\not=3$.

I don't have too many thoughts about this, other than that since 7 is a primitive root modulo 11, we know that this list of logarithms *must* contain all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ from $0$ to $p-2=9$.

I would appreciate any guidance anyone is able to give.

(As a disclaimer, this is not a homework problem, and I will not directly receive any academic credit for being able to solve it. I encountered some like it while studying for an exam and am curious what a good starting point might be.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x=b^t$, where $t$ is unknown. Now $b^{te}=n$ mod p, so you know $te$ mod (p-1) from the values stored and hence you solve for $t$ mod (p-1) and find $x=b^t$.

In the example, we have $x^7=3$, that is $7^{7t}=3$, and hence $7t=4$ mod 10, which yields $t=2$ and $x=49$ (mod 11), i.e. $x=5$.

Comment: That puts me on the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have too much info, we can solve if we stick to just  $x^7 = 3 \mod 11$ using Euler's theorem.

if n is a positive integer and a, n are coprime, b ≡ 1 mod φ(n), then a^b ≡ a mod n.

So we need to find the inverse of $7^{-1} \mod 10$, i.e. $7^{-1} = 3$. Note $10$ is the order φ(11) of prime number $11$.

Using Euler 
$x^7 = 3 \implies x = 3^3 \mod 11 \implies x = 27 \mod 11 \implies 
x = 5$